# Classification: Independence and Exchangeability

Tags: bayesian, classification

I noticed this in the source I was referring to:

In classification problems,

- The data should be independent and exchangeable within each class.
- Across classes, the data must not be independent.
- Otherwise, the data would not contain information about which class it is in.
- The data must be conditionally independent when conditioned on the class.

I don't really understand what this is supposed to mean. Take the example of a very simple spam filter that classifies emails into spam and not spam depending on the words of the email. What does it mean when it is said that the words in a class are independent and exchangeable from other words in the same class, and that words in one class must be dependent on words in another class? Am I misunderstanding the lines?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at spam emails, the words should be independent and exchangeable (of course, they aren't, due to sentence structure at the very least, but we'll ignore that for the purposes of this example.)  Non-spam emails should also have independent and exchangeable words.   But if you look at all the words together - not grouping them into "spam email words" and "non-spam email words" - they can't be independent if you want to use them to identify spam.  The "spam email words" should somehow be distinguishable from the "non-spam email words", because if they weren't, you wouldn't be able to distinguish spam from non-spam on the basis of the words.  So "spam email words" must somehow be more similar to each other than they are to "non-spam email words" and vice versa, which necessarily implies that they aren't independent *across classes*.